# Images is not displaying in ireport html format

Tags: ireport

I was trying for long:

I'm create report using iReport designer. In that its showing the images in all format (PDF, Excel, RTF), but while I'm trying to display in HTML format in JSP, the image is not displaying. What I want to do to solve this problem. I'm trying this for long time. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the source of the generated HTML? The image path might be wrongly set

Comment: i have seen the image path, its showing the wrong path only.. but i dont know how can i set.. if i set the correct path also it linking to the same error path only.. how can i solve dis..? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One thing to be aware of is that if you have two overlapping controls in HTML, one of the controls will not be displayed.  Be sure you do not have another control overlapping with the image control.

I have had this problem with text fields before.

Comment: This was my problem at last. Tried several hours, but this was the answer ... Thanks you mentioned that.

Comment: To make overlapping elements easier to spot:  Options > JasperReports Properties > select net.sf.jasperreports.allow.element.overlap > click the 'Modify property' button > set to false. 

Now try to preview and iReport will inform you of overlapping properties before it generates the report.

Answer (score 1):

For your image, try the Expression Class

```
'net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable'
```

and something like the following for the Image Expression:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance("image-dir/report-logo.gif")
```

In the jasper reports file (e.g. myreport.jrxml) the expression for the image would look like:

```
<image scaleImage="Clip" isUsingCache="false">
    <reportElement key="image-1" x="0" y="0" width="65" height="47"/>
    <imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable"><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance(image-dir"/report-logo.gif")]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

For Html reports an image servlet may be useful, which can be configured in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>image</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>image</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/report/image</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Java / Spring code to execute the report, which a.o. sets the image uri for the image servlet:

```
public ModelAndView createReport(HttpSession session, String reportName, String format) {

ApplicationContext context = this.getApplicationContext();
JasperReportsMultiFormatView report = new CollegeJasperReportsMultiFormatView(session); 
report.setUrl("/WEB-INF/reports/jasper/" + reportName + ".jasper");

Map<String, Object> model = getModel();
model.put("format", format);

Map parameters = new HashMap();
report.setExporterParameters(parameters);
parameters.put(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF8");
parameters.put(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "../report/image?image=");
parameters.put(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, Boolean.FALSE);

Properties contentDispositionMappings = new Properties();;
contentDispositionMappings.put(format, "inline; filename=report." + format);
report.setContentDispositionMappings(contentDispositionMappings);

report.setApplicationContext(context);      // this will convert the export parameters, so has to be called after setExportParameters()
return new ModelAndView(report, model);
}
```

Comment: hi markus, am tried with ur code..but it doesn't work for me.. can u provide full code to display my report in html view by using the jsp code..? thanks in advance

Comment: For html reports it could be necessary to configure jasper report's image servlet. See edited answer.

Comment: Hi,am running my jsp application frm netbeans IDE with default glassfish server, so my proj file contains glassfish-web.xml file. while am adding the image servlet to dat xml file its showing error. And again am tried to create a seperate file as web.xml..         
but dat aso not successful.. its shows d above error.. wat can i do..? culd u explain me? thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't know about Glassfish, but there must be a way to declare your specific servlets. Make sure the jasperreports jar file is in the classpath when starting the server (for the net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet class).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you can generate a HTML report and point to your image servlet for the newer JasperReports libraries (I am using 6.1.0), as a lot of the old functions are deprecated:

```
StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();        
HtmlExporter exporterHTML = new HtmlExporter();
SimpleExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint);
exporterHTML.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

SimpleHtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(sbuffer);
//pointing to the image servlet
HtmlResourceHandler imageHandler = new WebHtmlResourceHandler( request.getContextPath() + "/servlets/image?" + ImageServlet.IMAGE_NAME_REQUEST_PARAMETER
        + "={0}" + "&uuid=" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
exporterOutput.setImageHandler(imageHandler);

//setting some sonfigs for the report
SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration htmlConfig = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();
SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration htmlReportConfiguration = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();
htmlConfig.setHtmlFooter("");
htmlConfig.setHtmlHeader("");
htmlConfig.setBetweenPagesHtml("");
htmlReportConfiguration.setPageIndex(pageIndex);

exporterHTML.setConfiguration(htmlConfig);
exporterHTML.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
exporterHTML.setConfiguration(htmlReportConfiguration);

exporterHTML.exportReport();
```